# Job messages appears empty, while my Inbox indicates messages

Tags: support, bug, jobs-messages

I have jobs messages indicated in the inbox toolbar icon and in e-mails, however, when I click them or otherwise go to the jobs messages, it appears to have no messages at all. The JavaScript console shows the error below. This behaviour is consistent across [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) (Mac and iOS) and Google Chrome (Mac).

> Couldn't find args for module "Content/Ts/analytics.prizm.ts". Did you forget to call @JavaScript.Module?

Comment: Already reported: [Job messages not displayed](/q/411493/4642212).